# Can I define a C extern function required by a library without an extra compilation step?

Tags: c, gcc, shared-libraries, linker-errors

I have been provided a library `a` that expects there to be a function `b()` but does not implement it. It looks like this (I can't change this code):

**a.h**:

```c
void a();
```

**a.c**:

```c
#include "a.h"
extern void b();
void a() {
    b();
}
```

The library was compiled like this (assume all files in these examples are in the same directory for simplicity).:

```
gcc -shared a.c -o liba.so
```

I want to call `a()` in my code, so I write a program that looks like this:

**main_v1.c**:

```c
#include "a.h"
int main(void) {
    a();
    return 0;
}
```

If I try to compile this, I'll get a linker error because `b()` hasn't been defined:

```
gcc main_v1.c -L ./ -la -o main
```

```
.//liba.so: undefined reference to `b'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The simplest thing I can do is add a definition of `b()` right in my main.c:

**main_v2.c**:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "a.h"
void b() {
    printf("b");
}
int main(void) {
    a();
    return 0;
}
```

```
gcc main_v2.c -L ./ -la -o main
```

This works. But what if I don't want to define `b()` in my main.c? For example, if I want to be able to re-use my `b()` implementation elsewhere? One think I know I can do is compile it into a second library and link against it, like this:

**b_v1.c**:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
void b() {
    printf("b");
}
```

```
gcc -shared b_v1.c -o libb.so
gcc main_v1.c -L ./ -la -lb -o main
```

This works too. Note that -lb *must* come after -la; it won't work the other way around.

But I'd really like to avoid compiling another library. Why can't I just do this?:

**b.h**:

```c
void b();
```

**b_v2.c**:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "b.h"
void b() {
    printf("b");
}
```

**main_v3.c**:

```c
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"
int main(void) {
    a();
    return 0;
}
```

```
gcc main_v3.c -L ./ -la -o main
```

This doesn't work. I get the same linker error:

```
.//liba.so: undefined reference to `b'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Why not? How is this different from my first working example in main_v2.c? Is there a way to accomplish this without creating a separate library for `b()`?

Comment: In your last example, when are you compiling anything that has the definition (not declaration) for `b()`?

Comment: That was it! This *does* work, I had just forgotten to include b_v2.c in the compilation step. It should look like this:  `gcc main_v3.c b_v2.c -L ./ -la -o main`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mat pointed out, I was simply neglecting to include the b_v2.c source in the compilation step. This works:

```
gcc main_v3.c b_v2.c -L ./ -la -o main
```

Answer (score 0):

> How is this different from my first working example in main_v2.c?

In version 3, no implementation of `b()` is even compiled, much less linked into the final executable.  A declaration alone is not sufficient, and including a header is completely independent of compiling or linking an associated source file.

Note that your `a.c` has exactly as much of a declaration of `b()` as `main_v3.c` acquires from `b.h`, so if nothing in `main_v3.c` calls that function, then that header is not adding anything new or useful.

> Is there a way to accomplish this without creating a separate library for b()?

Sure, several.  But the easiest one for you to use might be to just name both your C source files on the same compilation command line:

```
gcc main_v1.c b.c -L. -la -o main
```

Note that I have chosen `main_v1` intentionally: since nothing in the file calls `b()`, it is not useful for a declaration of that function to appear in the file, whether directly or via header inclusion.

Answer (score 0):

a.h

```
void a();
```

a.c

```
void b();
void a() {
    b();
}
```

b.c

```
#include "a.h"
 #include <unistd.h>
void b()
{
 write(1, "test", 4);
}
```

compile

```
$> gcc *.c
```

exec

```
$> ./a.out
```